Memberships for 2023
I am a volunteer for a non profit organization of with approximately 400 members.   I very new to CIVICRM and have no past experience with any relationship management software. Our organization is  trying to do a comparison of membership numbers in 2023 and 2024. What is the best way to locate this information?
Thank you in advance.
Anna

This may be of help https://civicrm.org/blog/agilewarejustinfreeman/how-many-members-did-we-have-date-how-many-times-has-member-renewed-how

Civi keeps records of three key dates regarding memberships: join date being the date that a contact first joined as a member; start date - being the date that the most recent membership period began (membership period being the length of a standard membership - often 1 year); and expiry date - being the date that the most recent membership period ends.
Bear in mind that different orgs have different regimes for membership: for some, all memberships start on a given date, whilst for others memberships are rolling - i.e. membership starts on the date when the contact joins, and runs for the length of the membership period.
I'd start by running a couple of fairly straightforward searches, to find a list of contacts with memberships with an expiry dates in 2023 (i.e in the date range Jan 1 - Dec 31 2023), and a second search for contacts with memberships with an expiry date equal to or greater than Jan 1 2024.
This will give you two lists of contacts that should meet your requirement.
